# How to install chess.pgn on python?

Tags: software, pgn, python

I don't know how to import chess.pgn on Python.
I searched everywhere, but I didn't find anything. Can anybody here help me?

Comment: I guess you want `chess.pgn` from the python-chess library (?). The installation is covered in the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-chess/#installing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already installed python-chess via pip/conda/choco or your favourite package manager, then to use chess.pgn, in your .py files just call `from chess import pgn` or `import chess.pgn`. You have to explicitly write either import, even if you already have `import chess`.

Then you can use it like

```
from chess import pgn

with open("my_pgn_file.pgn", "r") as pf:
    game = pgn.read_game(pf)
```

If I had used `import chess.pgn` instead, then I call it by changing the last line to `game = chess.pgn.read_game(pf)`.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to install this library:

```
pip install python-chess
```

And make sure you're using the right `pip`, because still in some Linus distros `pip` and `python` are `python 2.x` and for `python 3.x` you should use `pip3` and `python3`. If you want to check try this:

```
pip --version
```

You will see an output like this that will tell you what python you're using, in my case it's 3.8:

> pip 19.2.3 from /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)